# appRouter is not fired on load

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to set up a router for my backbone application. However when i go to `localhost:8888/extractors` or `localhost:8888/extractors/new`. neither of the console messages are being outputted. How come when it is defined in the router itself?

```
require(['new-extractor-view', 'extractors-collection', 'backbone'], function (NewExtractorView, ExtractorsCollection) {
    'use strict';

    var extractorCollection = new ExtractorsCollection();

    new NewExtractorView({
        collection: extractorCollection
    });

    //
    // Initialize URL router
    //
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'extractors': 'extractorsRoute',
            'extractors/new': 'newExtractorRoute',
            '*actions': 'defaultRoute'
        }
    });

    var appRouter = new AppRouter;


    appRouter.on('route:extractorsRoute', function () {
        console.log('test1')
    });

    appRouter.on('route:newExtractorRoute', function () {
        console.log('test2')
    });


    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use url's **without `#`** you should initialize history like:

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true })
```

Read more about the [`pushState`](http://backbonejs.org/#History) option.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok to me, but I think you forgot the brackets when creating the new router:

```
var appRouter = new AppRouter();
```

Edit: Oh and I'm quite sure Backbone will only match `localhost:8888/#extractors` (with a leading hashtag) but not `localhost:8888/extractors` as described [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Router).